# How to pass an argument when using ::AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, &INDEX);

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a problem in using  ::AfxBeginThread in MFC.

I tried to make a thread and this is my code.

```
void CMyoControllerView::OnCbnSelchangeComboFist()
{
    int nIndex = m_combo_Fist.GetCurSel();
    int INDEX;

    if(nIndex != CB_ERR){ 
        CString str;  
        m_combo_Fist.GetLBText(nIndex, str); 

       if(str == "Left Click") {
           INDEX = 0;
       } else if(str == "Double Click") {
           INDEX = 1;
       } else if(str == "Right Click") {
           INDEX = 2;
       } else if(str == "Wheel Click") {
           INDEX = 3;
       } else {
           INDEX = 4;
       }
       pThread_Fist = ::AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, &INDEX);
    }
}
```

and ThreadFunc function is...

```
UINT CMyoControllerView::ThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{   
   int index= (int)pParam;
   if(index == 0) { }
   else if(index == 1) { } 
   ...

}
```

There is a problem in ::AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, &INDEX));

I want to pass an argument to "INDEX" (possible value: 0~4).

However, when I debugged this code, there were garbage value in "index" variable in ThreadFunc. (The value should be 0~4.)

I tried to use reinterpret_cast , reinterpret_cast and etc.
but I can't get right value.

What should I change to get right value in "index"variable?

(ps. I am not sure but I thought it could be a x64 or x86 problem. so I searched google and got nothing. 
I am using Windows 8 x64.)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are passing the argument `INDEX` is fine. The problem you run into is one of synchronization: `INDEX` is an automatic variable, that becomes invalid, when it goes out of scope, i.e. just before `CMyoControllerView::OnCbnSelchangeComboFist` returns. At that point your thread may not have read the variable, and once it does, it sees garbage. Plus, you're re-interpreting the `int*` as an `int` value, when trying to read it, so your `index` variable is the numeric value of the address of the `INDEX` variable.

The solution is to implement synchronization. After requesting to create a new thread, you have to wait for it to read the data passed to it. One solution is to use events.

Create a global [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) object to synchronize thread startup:

```
HANDLE g_hThreadRunning = ::CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL );
```

Change your thread creation code to wait for the thread to signal, that it's done reading the data ([WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx)):

```
void CMyoControllerView::OnCbnSelchangeComboFist() {

    // ...

    pThread_Fist = ::AfxBeginThread( ThreadFunc, &INDEX );
    ::WaitForSingleObject( g_hThreadRunning, INFINITE );
}
```

In your thread procedure, set the synchronization object to signaled, when done reading the data ([SetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211.aspx)). Note that you have to interpret `pParam` the same way you did, when you passed the parameter, i.e. as an `int*`:

```
UINT CMyoControllerView::ThreadFunc( LPVOID pParam ) {   
    int index = *static_cast<int*>( pParam );
    ::SetEvent( g_hThreadRunning );

    if(index == 0) { }
    else if(index == 1) { } 
    // ...
}
```

---

An alternative would be to have the `pParam` pointer argument carry an `int` instead:

```
pThread_Fist = ::AfxBeginThread( ThreadFunc, reinterpret_cast<void*>( INDEX ) );
```

and inside `ThreadFunc`:

```
int index = reinterpret_cast<int>( pParam );
```

Since this is passing the argument **by value**, you don't need any synchronization. However, this is not generally applicable. In particular, it can fail for certain platforms. It is not guaranteed to work (although it will for all platforms running Windows **today**).

Comment: Another common pattern is to allocate an object to hold the information you want to pass to the thread with `new`, pass the address of the object to the thread, and have the thread `delete` it when it's done with it.

Comment: @David: While common practice, it is generally a bad idea to pass ownership. The target thread may use a different memory allocator than the source thread, leading to subtle bugs like memory corruption.

Comment: The whole point of threads, the very reason they exist, is that they share all memory. If you have a platform that doesn't let you take advantage of this, and that requires you to keep the ownership of objects with particular threads, you're kind of missing the whole point. The vast majority of threads-using code passes ownership among threads. You couldn't even, for example, use a mutex to protect a vector. (What happens if the vector re-allocates?!) I mean, pretty much everything you do with threads would be prohibited by this rule! If this doesn't work, threads are unusable, IMO.

Comment: @David: C++ doesn't know threads (at least not until C++11, and even then, support is incomplete). Using the C++ allocator and passing **ownership** is still, in general, a bad idea. Passing a pointer for **access**, however, is fine. If you need to pass ownership, use an explicit memory allocator, that knows threads, e.g. `IMalloc`. Ownership for mutexes is established explicitly (e.g. [CreateMutex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30501602/1889329)), that doesn't deal with memory allocations at all.

Comment: You're basically arguing that the vast majority of code that uses threads is wrong, including (for example) all pre-C++11 code that allows multiple threads to modify a vector under the protection of a mutex. If this is some pet issue for you where it's you against the world, fine, but don't let your pet issue color the advice you give people who are trying to learn who need to learn how everyone else does things.

Comment: @David: I don't know about the *"vast majority of code"*, and never did quantify the amount either. I did, however, point out a real world issue. A common scenario where this can be a problem is [crossing a DLL boundary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx). If this is inaccurate, I'd suggest you outline, why. As for your vector example: The `std::vector` template has two template parameters. If necessary, you can instantiate the template with an appropriate allocator, that can cope with allocations and deallocations from different threads.

Comment: The solution is good because it's universal. E.g. one can use it to pass objects. The title of the question is "how to pass an argument" not "how to pass a 32-bit int". (And the former are the keywords that bring people here from google).

Answer (score 0):

Pass `INDEX` by value casting to `LPVOID`:

```
pThread_Fist = ::AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, (LPVOID)INDEX);
```

Your existing thread code is fine to make an opposite casting:

```
UINT CMyoControllerView::ThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
     int index= (int)pParam;
     ...
}
```

`LPVOID` size is enough to contain an integer value both for x86 and x64 platforms.

Comment: Interesting negative vote without any comments for simple and obviously correct answer.

Comment: C-style casts in a question tagged *C++*. Solution that is not generally applicable. Completely ignores potentially different alignment rules for pointers and `int`. It works by coincidence, hence the downvote.

Comment: @IInspectable: This solution is absolutely correct. I don't want to downvote your terrible synchronization solution because voting wars are prohibited. You have also copied my answer to your question later. Please concentrate on providing a good solutions and not on fighting with another members.

Comment: Why don't you post a comment on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30501602/1889329), pointing out, why the synchronization is *"terrible"*, and how to improve it. I **modified** your answer, and included it in my answer. Pointing out, why it is not recommended. Now that's something I wouldn't call *copying*.

Comment: @IInspectable: your solution is terrible because you suggest to use synchronization to pass simple integer value to thread. Then you copied my answer to your own post and downvoted my answer. Do you think this is sumo arena?

Comment: I added a **modified** version of your answer after the OP was all thrilled about it, as a reference to add appropriate critique. If you believe this is terribly unfair, you know how to get a moderator's attention for arbitration. Synchronization is the standard pattern to use, that is guaranteed to work, regardless of the data passed across. How does your proposed solution cope with passing a simple `__int64` when compiling for x86, for example?